# How to carry eggs without egg tray or egg carton?

Tags: eggs

When I don't have an egg tray or egg carton how to carry eggs without breaking them?

Comment: The best answer here is HIGHLY dependant upon 1) how far you have to carry them, 2) how they will be transported 3) what likely dangers they might experience 4) what materials you might have to hand. If you explain the circumstances a bit more, you might get some suggestions that are more suited to your needs.

Comment: You're right I was thinking to add that I always carry them on bike but I though ask  generally.

Comment: Cook them first?

Comment: How can I boil them in a shop and even if I can how can I fry them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the old classic methods used sawdust (dry sand also works): put a layer of sawdust in a (wood) box, nest some eggs into it (well separated from either other and the side/bottom of the box).  Add more sawdust, until you can nest another layer of eggs with similar separation between layers as between eggs in a layer.  Continue until you run out of eggs or space.

Another method (which also helps preserve freshness without refrigeration) is to pour barely-melted bacon fat (or plain lard) over the eggs, which are nested into a container like a bucket.  The fat prevents movement, which would be required for the eggs to break; it also excludes air, reducing the speed of spoilage.

You could use a tube (like the core roll from aluminum foil, which is about the right size) -- plug the tube with something soft and resilient, like high density foam, add an egg, another plug, etc.

What all of these methods have in common is that they immobilize the eggs, as well as preventing external impact.  Anything that accomplishes both ought to work.

Comment: Well this methods need lot of work get all of this things sawdust and you mentioned in the answer.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Swapnil That's why we mostly use molded egg crate (either plastic or pulp material) these days.

Comment: Yes you are right I thought if there are easy ways to do. So may I can have steel tin that may prevent from breaking.